# Use a parameter as jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I'm trying to use a parameter to define a jQuery method like:

```
function first(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) {
   $(parameter1).parameter2(parameter3);
}
```

I want to call it with `onclick="first('#mydiv', 'fadeIn', 'slow');"` but it doesn't work. The console says:

> (...).parameter2 is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your jQuery object is missing the `$`. Secondly, to access a property of an object you need to use bracket notation. Try this:

```
function first(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) {
   $(parameter1)[parameter2](parameter3);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/41hedh6d/)

Comment: I did a correction about the `$`, but StackExchange was offline for a while, so I lost that change. But hey, it worked! Thank you, Rory :)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, other user did it. And I'll accept it as an answer in 5 minutes. I can't do it yet u.u

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i did downvote. missclick. sry. upvoted :D

Comment: Accepted! Thank you again.